# If-else statement trouble in Visual studio 2015

Tags: c, if-statement

I'm a beginner in programming.
I made a simple program in C# but it doesn't work properly.
When I type "rezistenta" it should run the condition
`if (valoare=="rezistenta")`
When I type "capacitate" it should run the second if:
`if(valoare=="capacitate")`
In both cases the program runs the last else, it skips the first 2 if conditions.

The  program:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS  //directive preprocesor
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>


void main(void)
{
    char valoare[100];
    float C1, C2, CS, CP;
    float R1, R2, Rs, Rp;


    printf("\nCapacitate sau Rezistenta? ");
    scanf("%s", &valoare);
    printf("\nAti introdus= %s", valoare);

    if (valoare == "rezistenta")
    {
        printf("\nIntroduceti valorile rezistentelor: ");
        scanf("%f%f", &R1, &R2);
        Rs = R1 + R2;
        printf("\nRezistenta echivalenta serie este: *%6.3f*", Rs);
        Rp = (R1*R2) / (R1 + R2);
        printf("\nRezistenta echivalenta paralel: *%6.3f*", Rp);
    }
    else if (valoare == "capacitate")
    {
        printf("\nIntroduceti valorile capacitatilor: ");
        scanf("%f%f", &C1, &C2);
        CS = (C1*C2) / (C1 + C2);
        printf("\nValoarea capacitatilor serie este = *%-6.4f*", CS);
        CP = C1 + C2;
        printf("\nValoarea capacitatilor in paralel este= *%-6.4f*", CP);
    }
    else
        printf("\nSunteti nehotarat vi le dau pe amandoua");



    printf("\nIntroduceti valorile rezistentelor: ");
    scanf("%f%f", &R1, &R2);
    Rs = R1 + R2;
    printf("\nRezistenta echivalenta serie este: *%6.3f*", Rs);
    Rp = (R1*R2) / (R1 + R2);
    printf("\nRezistenta echivalenta paralel: *%6.3f*", Rp);

    printf("\nIntroduceti valorile capacitatilor: ");
    scanf("%f%f", &C1, &C2);
    CS = (C1*C2) / (C1 + C2);
    printf("\nValoarea capacitatilor serie este = *%-6.4f*", CS);
    CP = C1 + C2;
    printf("\nValoarea capacitatilor in paralel este= *%-6.4f*", CP);



    _getch();



}//end main
```

Comment: Are you sure it's C#? Not C++?

Comment: It doesn't look like `C#` Check out this question on comparing string in C: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004237/how-do-i-properly-compare-strings-in-c

Comment: Looks like C programming to me.

Comment: Is C, I'm soryy, I'm new in programming stuff, now I am learning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

are you sure this is C#? It look like C. For C, it use printf(""), but C# should be Console.WriteLine("") or Console.Write("")

Anyhow, if you are using C, you cannot do the string comparison like this:

```
if (valoare == "rezistenta")     //this is wrong
```

The correct way should be:

```
if(strcmp(valoare, "rezistenta") == 0)
```

Of course you have to include the library on top:

```
#include <string.h>
```

Please kindly have a try.

Comment: Thank you it works, you were right is C. I thought C and C# are the same. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 2):

Here you can not compare like this way. 
Here

```
 if(strcmp(valoare,"rezistenta")==0)
{
//...
}
```

and include a header file

```
#include<string.h>
```